# Accessing Pivot tables from another Sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Very novice user here, just getting my feet wet.  Please excuse this if it's an idiotic question - I'm quite sure what I'm doing yet.

I'm creating a userform with VBA and Excel.  I've been successful in learning how to pull information from a pivot table so far, but I've run into a hitch.

When run my userform from another sheet it can't find the pivot table.  Here's the code I'm using.

`Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)`

Works perfectly when I'm one that sheet, but I envision a scenario where I have multiple pivots on different sheets and will want to call info and cross-reference the data.

I thought maybe  `Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(1)`  would work, but of course it doesn't.  Obviously I don't yet quite understand how to use a pivot table variable.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this?  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you have multiple pivots on different sheets then how would your code determine which one should be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you open UserForm, workbook with UserForm open will be the active one. If I understand correctly, you want to refer to 1st object of PivotTables collection on a different sheet. To do so, define path of the file with pivot table, example below:

```
Dim path as string
Dim wbk as workbook
Dim PT As PivotTable   

path= "C:\folder1\folder2\yourfile.extension"

set wbk = workbooks.open(path)
Set PT = wbk.worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
'do your actions, save the file if you want to keep changes
wbk.close
set wbk = nothing
```

Alternatively work on all Pivot Tables in your worksheet, instead of:

```
Set PT = wbk.worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
```

You can use a loop through collection, this example refreshes tables:

```
 For Each PT In wbk.worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        PT.RefreshTable
 Next PT
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!